Example use case for threads hierarchy in CUDA
I'm learning CUDA and read that the point of the thread hierarchy is to allow for scalability and compatibility across GPUs with differing capabilities. (I don't know if this is the sole benefit).
In NVIDIA's doc (Section 1.3), there is a small picture highlighting how an 8 block, "multi-threaded" CUDA-program can be run on both a GPU with 2 SMs and a GPU with 4 SMs. However, I fail to understand why this could not be achieved by just having threads, as opposed to having the grid and block abstractions.
Please could someone provide an example use case for the threads hierarchy, where having just threads would be insufficient?

Any kernel that uses shared memory/block synchronization? E.g. reductions, scans, ... Basically anything that is not trivially parallel and therefore benefits from local communication or even kernels that are trivially parallel but not ideal in terms of memory access/data reuse like optimized matrix-matrix product kernels.

This becomes clear if one keeps reading after the introduction. 2.2. Thread Hierarchy: "Threads within a block can cooperate by sharing data through some shared memory and by synchronizing their execution to coordinate memory accesses."

@paleonix Thanks. I have actually read the first 4 sections, but was not sure on how the shared memory/other features were used, and whether they were related to the thread hierarchy, or simply an independent HW feature. Thus I asked for an example. I am looking into the examples you shared, and I think they help a lot, so thanks. Also, my question implies the sub-question; is it not possible to just have shared memory across all threads instead of across a thread block? I believe the answer to this is due to memory management across warps...

@paleonix However I don't believe your comment addresses how the hierarchy makes cross-compatibility easier?

When someone familiar with CUDA and the hardware it is supposed to run on thinks about a worse alternative to this scalable paradigm, they probably think of directly programming the hardware on the warp and SM level instead of on the thread and block level. Having just threads doesn't make sense in that context (even the introduction mentions cooperation among threads of a block). In such a hypothetical programming model writing basic kernels in a scalable way would need much more boilerplate (like querying the number of SMs to figure out how much work every SM has to do).

A grid can (and usually has) more threads than can run simultaneously on a GPU. The GPU can only guarantee that all threads within a single thread block run at the same time (and on the same streaming multiprocessor; SM). Therefore they can communicate easily. Meanwhile, GPUs of different performance levels (different numbers of SM) can run the same grid in different times by running fewer or more thread blocks in parallel or after each other. You as a programmer don't need to worry about the exact number that runs at the same time

"is it not possible to just have shared memory across all threads instead of across a thread block?" Global memory is memory shared among all thread blocks. But access (to uncached regions) is expensive because DRAM is physically off-chip. Shared memory is not only on-chip (like L2 cache) but local to the SM. Accessing the shared memory from another block on another SM is generally (assuming it were possible) much more expensive. The block-clusters on Hopper go a little into that direction but generally no, "global shared memory" does not make sense given the hardware architecture.

TL;DR: Cooperation local to a block (and therefore SM) is cheap and therefore desirable for everything but the most basic kernels. You need to define what is local and what isn't to be able to make use of the locality. So a hierarchy is inevitable. What makes the programming model scalable is not the presence of a hierarchy but the fact that that hierarchy is an abstraction of the actual hardware hierarchy that allows writing and efficiently launching kernels with little to no knowledge of the exact hardware present in the system.

Needed time to digest, but all makes sense. Thanks both paleonix and @Homer512.

The thread hierarchy, just like the memory hierarchy is all about locality of reference.
Warp
Threads are grouped in clumps of 32: a warp. Threads in a warp can share data using the shfl_[up_,down_,xor_,_]sync, warp reduction, warp match and the (very useful) warp vote instructions.
Threads in a warp have cheap synchronisation: __syncwarp
Thread block
The next step up is a thread block, up to 32 warps (1024 threads) that collaborate in the same multiprocessor (SM). There are no dedicated instructions for intra-block communication, but threads in a block can used __shared__ memory to exchange data. This is almost as efficient as __shfl_sync.
Grid block
Next up we have multiprocessors (SMs), a GPU can have 20 or 100 of those. These (prior to Blackwell) can only communicate via global memory. A thread in SM a stores data in global mem, and a thread in SM b reads that data.
Two grid blocks typically run on different SMs (and if they happen to be on the same SM, they cannot share __shared__ memory).
(In Blackwell, a thread in SM a can move data from its shared memory to the shared memory in another SM).
Different GPUs
The next level of the hierarchy is running your program on multiple GPUs on the same machine.
These can only communicate across the GPU interlink (whose name escapes me).
This is obviously even slower and more complicated.
Different machines
the final level is running on different machines which communicate via the network (either local, or over the internet).
When to use what
Obviously a single warp can only perform 32 concurrent tasks.
A block only 1024 concurrent tasks, and so on.
If you have limited time, and you need to use all 20x32x32 = 20480 threads on a GPU with 20 SMs, then you need a grid block, and you'll have to design your program accordingly.
Every step up the thread pyramid executes faster than the one below it, because the distance on the chip between threads is smaller, allowing the manufacturer to design fast interconnects.
The hierarchy also eases the programming model, so that different versions of GPUs can be programmed in the same way.
But why?
Designing it like this, allows the GPU to provide fast options at warp/block level. If we only had grid blocks, then every thread will be forced to only communicate via global memory.
The following example to get the maximum value (out of 32) from a bitonic sequence that looks like this:
  /\
 /  \  e.g.:  1, 2, 10, 20, 30, 500, 400, 3, 0.
/


__device__ int GetMaxValue(const int value) {  //every thread has different value
    //the input must be a bitonic sequence
    constexpr auto All = -1u; //all threads in the warp take part
    const auto Neighbor = __shfl_down_sync(All, value, 1); //thread 31 gets its own value back
    const auto mask = __ballot_sync(All, Neighbor > value); //e.g. 0b0000000011111111
    const auto MaxBit = __popc(mask); //The thread holding the max value
    const auto result = __shfl_sync(All, value, MaxBit); //share max value with all
    return result; //all threads return the same result
}

is much faster than the equivalent code using only global memory, if we pretend that warps and blocks do not exist:
__device__ int GetMaxValue_NoWarp(int value, int* tempstorage) {
    tempstorage[32] = 0;
    tempstorage[threadIdx.x] = value;
    __syncthreads();
    const auto Neighbor = tempstorage[threadIdx.x + 1];
    if (threadIdx.x == 31) { Neighbor = value; }
    const auto diff = int(Neighbor > value); 
    atomicOr(&tempstorage[32], diff << threadIdx.x);
    __syncthreads();
    const auto mask = tempstorage[32];
    const auto MaxBit = __popc(mask); 
    result = tempstorage[MaxBit];
    return result;
} 

Even a single read from tempstorage takes longer than all of GetMaxValue, and GetMaxValue_NoWarp needs many reads and writes, because it does not have a fast mechanism to share data between threads.

Thanks :). Example was helpful, but as I'm new to CUDA, I found the code quite hard to follow. To readers in a similar position, the examples given in the comments were simpler in this regard.

However, I am confused with the way you have explained the hierarchy. I have seen resources referring to the "programmer's viewpoint" and the "hardware viewpoint", where they state that warps are a hardware construct, whereas the threads, blocks and grids are programming constructs. In your answer you use both together in the same hierarchy. This suggests that they are all programming constructs?

@ThePhysicsOverthinker, Warps are a programming construct. In reality the 32 threads in a warp are only backed by 16 actual execution cores that take turns executing the data. I fail to see the difference though. A block maps to a multiprocessor, so is that a hardware or programming construct? Technically you can ignore warps and just use the threadIdx to partition work, but if you do you miss out on a lot of performance. The main reason I include warps is that if you make threads in the same warp execute divergent code you will get terrible performance (up to 32x slower than max).
